flyway: is there any way to run flyway scripts which are embedded in a java project manually against local db?
We have a very large spring boot app with many modules.  This java is almost impossible to run locally against a local db.
In one of the services is a directory src/main/resources/db/migration Which contains a whole lot of .sql scripts.
I want to run these scripts against a local db to check what database is created from scratch (as opposed the very long running stage and prod DBs which have also been hacked manually so are different from the flyway scrpts unfortunately and I want to compare the differences to clean it up).
Is there a way to run all the sql scripts to create a local db?  I guess I could import each sql file into DBeaver and run as script, but this would take along time and I could easily get them out of order.
I tried installing flyway windows app, but this can only import projects in a specific directory format with migrations/ schema-model flyway.toml etc.  WE dont have any of these files or this structure unfortunately.
I am hoping someone might have written a windows or git-bash script which will read each sql file in order, and run it against a local db with user/pass etc specified on the command line?
If I was running unix or osX, I might have tried to hack it by creating a new project via flyway, then creating a symbolic link between the generated "migrations" folder to the java projects "migration" folder, but I assume windows (10) doesn't have os features like symbolic links.

The solution was to use mlink on windows (use ln -s on unix).

create a new flyway client project in any dir.

go to that dir and delete the migrations folder.

link your migrations folder to this folder, e.g.
mklink /d migrations \Users\me\dev\myproject\mymodule\src\main\resources\db\migration


Then refresh the project in the flyway client, add your target database and you can run migrations without having to build and run your spring boot application.
